# Notifying Google about domain redirection

Tags: pagerank

I have some domains to catch spelling mistakes, for example

```
http://www.mysupredomain.com
http://www.mysuperrdomain.com
http://www.msuperdomain.com
```

They all redirect to

```
http://www.mysuperdomain.com
```

(This is just an example)

I have noticed that these spelling-error-catching domains are not necessary, and I would like to abdandon these.

However, I think that Google might not like having domains suddenly not being reachable anymore.

Is there a way to tell Google that I will abandon these domains so that I will not get a lower page rank?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no need to. A redirect should not be seen as a link, so it doesn't count in the page ranks of your main domain.

If the domains did not redirect but instead feed the same content, your ranking could even become higher after eliminating them. Duplicate content (same content different URL) cannibalize on each others page rankings.

Your page rank could be affected negatively if there are many links to those aliases. All those links become invalid and are no longer counted in the page rank of your actual domain.